# Why won't any of my http methods work from my new router folder? and how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my first web dev project. I am basically trying to make a simple website to sell light sabers. The goal is to be able to create an account, login, add, edit and delete light sabers. Be able to add them to cart and checkout. I am using node.js, express, and mongoDB in visual studio code. I am also learning github throughout the process. As of now I have the layout of the website mostly set up. Am able to create accounts and login. I am currently stuck on creating items(light sabers) and saving them in the mongoDB database. Specifically my http methods in the routes/items files are not working, they were working previously in the app.js file but I decided to move everything for organizational purposes. Again, this is my first time working with any of this tech and this project is a work in progress, any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code: There is a lot of code not being used and its kind of a mess. I know..

app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local');
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var router = express.Router();

const app = express();

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const itemsRouter = require('./routes/items')



 //npm install ejs body-parser mongoose passport passport 
    var uri = "mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00- 
 hnxfk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01- 
 hnxfk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02- 
 hnxfk.mongodb.net:27017/test? 
 ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard- 
 0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    var localHost = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Project2SamJoshEricRoy"
    mongoose.connect(uri,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: 
true });

var User = require('./models/user');
var Item = require('./models/item');

// var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(require('express-session')({

    secret: "application secret shhhh",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()))
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', indexRouter)

app.use('/items', itemsRouter)




 //create account 
 app.get("/createAccount",(req,res)=> {
    res.render("createAccount");

});

app.get('/createAccount', function(req,res) {
    res.render('createAccount'); 
});


app.post("/createAccount",(req,res)=> {
    req.body.username;
    req.body.password;
    User.register(new 
User({username:req.body.username}),req.body.password, 
(err,user) =>{
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);

            return res.render("createAccount");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,() => {
            res.redirect('/login');
            console.log(req.body.username
                +  " " + req.body.password);
            console.log(user);

        });

    });
});


//login

app.get("/login",(req,res) => {
    res.render("login")
    User.find(function(err,users) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        // console.log(users);
    })
});


app.post('/login',passport.authenticate("local",{

    successRedirect: "/lightsabers",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}),(req,res)=> {

});



function isLoggedIn(req,res,next) {
    console.log("CALL")
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("logged in ");
        return next();

    }
    res.redirect("/login");
    console.log("error logging in");
}


//logout 

app.get("/logout",(req,res)=> {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});


//lightsabers

//app.get("/lightsabers",isLoggedIn,(req,res)=> {
    //res.render("lightsabers",{user: req.user});
    //console.log(req.user);
//});



//shopping cart
app.get("/cart",(req,res)=> {
    res.render("cart");

});

app.get('/createLightsaber',(req,res)=> {
    res.render("newItem",{user:req.User});
    console.log("user is with us");
    console.log(req.user)
});

app.get('/updateItem',(req,res)=> {
    res.render("updateLightsaber");

});

app.get('/deleteLightsaber',(req,res)=> {
    res.render("updateLightsaber");

});
```

/routes/index.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

module.exports = router
```

routes/items.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Item = require('../models/item')

//display page
router.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.render("newItem");
});


// all items route
router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{
    try{ 
        const items = await Item.find({})
        res.render('items/newItem', {item: new Item() })

    } catch {
        res.redirect('/')
    }
})

//new item route (display form)
router.get('/newItem', (req, res) => {
    res.render('items/newItem', {item: new Item() })
})

// create new item route (actual creation)
router.post('/newItem', async (req,res) => {
    const item = new Item({
        color:req.body.color,
        price:req.body.price, 
        link:req.body.link
    })
    try{
        const newItem = await item.save()
        res.redirect('lightsabers')
    } catch {
        res.render('items/newItem', {
            item: item,
            errorMessage:'Error creating item'
        })
    }

}) 


/update item 
    app.get("/updateItem",(req,res)=> {
        res.render("updateItem");

    });

module.exports = router
```

newItem.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Adding New Item </h1>


        <form action="/items" method="POST">
        <h2>

            Color: <input type="text" name="color"><br>    
            Price: <input type="text" name="price"><br>
            Image Link:<input type="text" name="link"><br>


            <br><br>
            <button id="addItem">Add Item</button>

            <%= typeof(message) != "undefined"?message:"" %>
        </h2>

        </form> 
                <form action="/lightsabers">
          <h2><button> Back </button></h2>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/app.js"> 
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you wish to see any other parts of the code let me know. I may be forgetting something important.

Comment: Questions here should have the relevant code pasted into the question itself and formatted appropriately.  This is because one of the key values of stackoverflow is as a long term Q&A reference and if your code is only available via a link, those links tend to go stale or get changed after a little while and then the question is useless as a reference.  If you write a nice specific question here with appropriate code in it and clear descriptions of the problem and what diagnostics you've gathered, you will usually get a quick answer.

Comment: Also be specific about which exact route you're asking about and when you say "my router.post() is not working", explain exactly what that means.  "not working" is not a description of the problem.  Do you get an error?  What exactly happens?

Comment: wow you guys reply fast. I just made some edits to the code pasted and the description. I am now realizing none of my http methods are working when I have it set up this way. and no error specifically. Just says cannot get or cannot post /newItem on the webpage.

Comment: MAJOR EDITS, CODE IS NOW in the post. Thanks for letting me know. the github wasnt even up to date lol..

Comment: Which route is the problem?  How are you posting to it?  Can you show the client code/form that does the post?  If `newItem.ejs` contains the form you're using to post, then it appears to have an `action="/items"`, but it looks like the `router.post("/newItem", ...)` route is hooked up to serve the URL `/items/newItem`.

Comment: Hi jfriend. Currently I cant even render the newItem.ejs page, so this means im having issues with connecting the routes, starting with just the first router.get( res.render) method